# Relative importing modules from parent folder subfolder

Tags: python, import, module, python-2.7

Given a directory structure like this

```
main/
    common/
        foo.py
    A/
        src/
            bar.py
```

How can I use Python's *relative imports* to import `foo` from `bar`? I've got a working solution by adding it to the path, but this is ugly. Is there a way to simply do with a single `import` in Python 2.7?

This is a more complex version of this question:

[Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The correct relative import would be this:

```
from ...common import foo
```

However, relative imports are only meant to work within one package. If `main` is a package, then you can use relative imports here. If `main` is not a package, you cannot.

Thus, if you're running a script in `/main/` and doing something like `import A.src.bar`, then that relative import will fail with "Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package". This is because the relative import is trying to import something outside of the toplevel package `A`.

However, if you're running a script in `/` and doing something like `import main.A.src.bar`, then that relative import will succeed because `main` is now a package. In that case, the following two would be equivalent:

```
from ...common import foo
from main.common import foo
```

To answer your comment: the meaning of the `.` doesn't change depending on where the script was run from, it changes depending on what the package structure is.

Comment: so, what is a solution for first case you said?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use relative imports, you have to have a package. In this example I think 'main' folder is the best candidate to be the top level package. Make a `__init__.py` inside 'main' folder and put the following code inside it to make it the top level folder in package:

```
__package__ = ''
```

Now you can use relative imports:

```
from ...common import foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with framework that uses OPSEC practices to limit the top-level-project of scripts but you need to import a local library from another place without copy-paste the same library for every script... (the reason cause im here) You can bypass the problem with a simbolic link to the folder that contains the code.

4 your example its like:

```
cd path2/A
ln -s path2/main/common common
```

then you can import in bar.py with

```
from A.common.foo import class
```

But if you do this instead of creating __init__.py's when its required then you have my intense dissaproval.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).