# Accessing code in adjacent files

Tags: python, directory, python-import, sys, sys.path

I have code in one folder, and want to import code in an adjacent folder like this:

```
I am trying to import a python file in innerLayer2, into a file in innerLayer1
outerLayer:
           innerLayer1
                      main.py
           innerLayer2 
                      functions.py
```

I created the following function to solve my problem, but there must be an easier way? This only works on windows aswell and I need it to work on both linux and windows.

```
# main.py
import sys    
def goBackToFile(layerBackName, otherFile):
        for path in sys.path:
            titles = path.split('\\')
            for index, name in enumerate(titles):
                if name == layerBackName:
                    finalPath = '\\'.join(titles[:index+1])
                    return finalPath + '\\' + otherFile if otherFile != False else finalPath


    sys.path.append(goBackToFile('outerLayer','innerLayer2'))
    import functions
```

Is there an easier method which will work on all operating systems?

Edit: I know the easiest method is to put innerLayer2 inside of innerLayer1 but I cannot do that in this scenario. The files have to be adjacent.

Edit: Upon analysing answers this has received I have discovered the easiest method and have posted it as an answer below. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: I have typed the answer and then found a possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative importing modules from parent folder subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon analysing answers I have received I have discovered the easiest solution: simply use this syntax to add the outerLayer directory to sys.path then import functions from innerLayer2:

```
# main.py
import sys
sys.path.append('..') # adds outerLayer to the sys.path (one layer up)
from innerLayer2 import functions
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.` and `..` to address within package structure as specified by [PEP 328](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) et al.

Suppose you have the following structure:

```
proj/
     script.py       # supposed to be installed in bin folder
     mypackage/      # supposed to be installed in sitelib folder
         __init__.py # defines default exports if any
         Inner1/
             __init__.py    # defines default exports from Inner1 if any
             main.py
         Inner2/
             __init__.py    # defines default exports from Inner2 if any
             functions.py
```

Inner1.main should contain import string like this:

```
from ..Inner2 import functions
```

Comment: This would work if I was dealing with a package, in my scenario this just leads to ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: I have stumbled upon the perfect answer to my problem and have posted it as an answer. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the current **directory** design, I would suggest using a combination of `sys` and `os` to simplify your code:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
from innerLayer2 import functions
```

Comment: This works well thankyou but have stumbled upon even simpler syntax which works just aswell, I have posted it as an answer for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

Move the `innerLayer2` folder to inside the `innerLayer1` folder
Add an empty file named `__init__.py` on the `innerLayer2`
On the `main.py` use the following:

```
 import innerLayer2.functions as innerLayer2
 # Eg of usage:
 # innerLayer2.sum(1, 2)
```

Comment: In this scenario I cannot put the innerLayer2 inside innerLayer1, if i could put it inside one another then I would use sys.append('innerLayer2) then just import functions instead of your method.

Comment: @user3159253 provided a generic answer which does not require any changes on your structure