# Python: Unable to import class from another file in different directory

Tags: python, pycharm

I have following directory structure:
ProjectRoot is root project directory. It contains directory 'a' which has mypython.py, which in turn contains a class MyPython. At same level as 'a', there is another directory 'b', which contains file named another.py.

[image]

I am trying to import MyPython class in another.py as:

```
from a.mypython import MyPython
```

But during execution this gives error as:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'

I event tried to put __init__.py' in a as suggested by many, but still no success.

How to get it working? Its Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing `python b/another.py`, this cannot work. Please try `python -m b.another` instead (after `touch a/__init__.py`).

You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder) for more information.

Comment: I just do 'python another.py' inside directory b.

Comment: If you run python inside directory b, then `a` is not under `PYTHONPATH` and hence you can't import it.