# Python not able to import file

Tags: python, python-3.x

As you can see in screenshot i have one file queryconfig.py which have some methods which i want to use in my validate.py
But I am not able to import this by 'from configs import queryconfig'
What I am doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post screenshots. Post the code as `formatet text`. And also post the complete error message.

Comment: Have you tried putting a . infront of configs as it's traversing into a sub directory?

Comment: I think this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something

Comment: yes i tried adding . but no effect

Comment: What's the PYTHONPATH for the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named <something>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476403/importerror-no-module-named-something)

Comment: @KlausD. C:\Users\uname\PycharmProjects\ref-data\srm-config-qa-test

Comment: You should add `arm-config` to it.

Comment: @buhtz Lets not be dogmatic.  It’s not *code*, it is a directory structure.  A pic seems ok, though the output of the `tree` utility might be even better.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder  maybe use `..configs` ?  I avoid relative imports myself so not sure.